Activating Python from Virtual Environment in VS Code For File Created On Another Laptop
I always create a virtual environment when writing code.  When I open a folder in VS code, I usually type source .venv/bin/activate to activate the virtual environment and run code.
Today, I reformatted my MacBook, was having issues, and reinstalled the latest version of Python and VS Code.  When I try to run my code now using the same procedure as above, it uses the global python environment.  So in VS Code command line, the options displayed for selecting the interpreter is either the latest version 3.13 or the one on my laptop by default 3.9.6.  However the one I created in the virtual environment doesn't show.  VS Code Screen
Interestingly, if I create a new folder and virtual environment, I'm able to select the python interpreter in my virtual environment. Python Interpreter in Virtual Environment
But if I open a folder created on my Mac before I reformatted it, I don't have the option to select the python interpreter in my virtual environment.
I feel like I tried everything, including copying the path to the python3.12 in my .venv/bin folder to manually select the interpreter (/Users/meworld/Documents/Programming/Python Files/Data_Science/.venv/bin/python3.12), but still no luck.
What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  As a side note, the python interpreter I used previously is 3.12 and the latest version in my global environment is 3.13.  Not sure if this has any impact.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question is similar to: Removed Python, can I still use the the virtual environment?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try the following steps to 'start fresh' and see if a new virtual env resolves anything:

Ensure VS Code is configured to detect virtual environments:

Go to Settings (Preferences) in VS Code.
Search for python.venvPath and set it to the directory containing your virtual environment (e.g., /Users/meworld/Documents/Programming/Python Files/Data_Science).


Recreate the .venv:

If the .venv was created before you reformatted, it might not be properly detected. Consider deleting and recreating the virtual environment using:
python3.12 -m venv .venv


Then activate it and install dependencies.


Clear Python extension cache:

Run the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette, and click Enter interpreter path.... Select the path to your .venv/bin/python3.12 manually.
Restart VS Code.


Check .vscode/settings.json:

Ensure there's no outdated reference to a previous Python path in .vscode/settings.json that could be interfering.




Thanks Erik.  I tried all your suggestions but none worked.  So I deleted my virtual environment and created a new one and installed all the required packages.   This is not efficient, I'm sure there's an easier way, but at least it worked.
